# How to test DbContext and fluent API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit, ef-core-2.1

In my ASP.NET Core web application, I'm using EF Core to connect to a SQL Server database. I have my `DbContext` object and a bunch of `DbSet`s. I'm trying to write integration tests, to basically test `DbContext`, its tables and relationships.

I've never done such test so I'm struggling a little bit with my decision how to do it. I watched Jason Roberts PluralSight course *"ASP.NET Core MVC Testing Fundamentals"*, but no such tests were even mentioned. So now I'm not sure if such tests are common practice in enterprises.

My goal is to be 100% sure, with one click, that the database behind the connection string is exactly as my app is expecting to be. That there are tables with FKs I'm expecting AND what's the most important - my fluent API configuration is correct as well.

Here's what I have today:

```
    [Fact]
    public void IncludeAuthor()
    {            
        var _context = new BookstoreContext(_connectionString); // Hardcoded in the test's constructor
        var book = _context.Books
            .Include(b => b.Author)
            .FirstOrDefault();     

        Assert.NotNull(book);
        Assert.NotNull(book.Author);
    }
```

Is this the right way to handle these kinda tests?

Should I test against real database? (development db of course)

Comment: if testing for integration, what i would normally do is add, select, edit and delete to see if *changes* have worked

Comment: Do you know how to debug in vs?

Comment: Remember that most testing frameworks, including xunit, will run tests asynchronously - many of them at a time. You should either turn this off, or make sure that tests will not interfere with each other by making modifications on the db that may break other tests.

Comment: You could use InMemoryDatabase for these tests

Answer (score 1):

I dont usually do integration testing, i use MOQ, but if required to do integration testing, i normally test is adding first, select, update then delete. But I am the only one connected/using it as it will cause error if it is being used

Test For Adding

```
private int _addedId {get; set;}


var _context = new BookstoreContext(_connectionString);

var book = new Book
{
    Property1 = "BookName",
    Property2 = "BookSomething",
    Author = //add new or select from given
}

_context.Books.Add(book);
_context.SaveChanges();

var recentlyAddedBook = _context.Book.Include(b => b.Author).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

Assert.AreEqual(book.Id, recentlyAddedBook.Id);
_addedId = book.Id;
```

Test for select

```
var book = _context.Books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == _addedId);

Assert.AreEqual(book.Property1, "BookName");
Assert.IsNotNull(book);
```

Test for update

```
var book = _context.Books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == _addedId);
book.PropertyName = "SomethingChange";
_context.SaveChanges();
//additional request to see if changes are really made in db
var updateBook = _context.Book.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == _addedId);

Assert.IsNotNull(updateBook);
Assert.AreEqual(book.PropertyName, updateBook.PropertyName);
```

Test For Delete

```
var book = _context.Books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == _addedId);
_context.Remove(book);
_context.SaveChanges();

//get again and it should be null
var recentlyDeleted = _context.Books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == _addedId);

Assert.IsNull(recentlyDeleted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) it helps you kind of simulate an interaction with DB without actually interacting with real data base.

Here is the [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/478504/Moq-Mock-Database) on how to use it with Database on **codeproject** it will explain it to you with examples.

> PS. The best practices of using `Moq` is to use it with Dependency
>   Injection

Moq [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq/).

Comment: Moq is a nice library but there will be one very important difference when using it. Your fluent API will use LinqToObject instead LinqToSql. In many cases that is fine but sometimes it works differently.

Comment: @JakubRusilko I didn't knew that, thank you for the information.

Comment: `box/unbox/ConvertTo...` will work with moq in `Where` clause not on `linq2sql` if it is executed on db but will work if executed on memory

Answer (score 0):

Integration test is basically carried out with real database , if your intention is to test it through MOQ database then you can use below way:

1. Entityframework.InMemory package : Violates referential integrity constraints
2. Entityframework.SqlLite package : Provides referential integrity constraints

Ways to use it are as follow .

In a separate class implement FakeBookstoreContext

```
public class FakeBookstoreContext : IDisposable
{
    public BookstoreContext `enter code here`m_context;

    public FakeBookstoreContext()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        connection.Open();

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BookstoreContext>()
            .UseSqlite(connection)
            .Options;

        m_context = new BookstoreContext(options);
        m_context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        m_context.Database.EnsureDeleted();

        m_context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In the integration test inject the above FakeBookstoreContext and continue testing as below

YourclassToTest y = new YourclassToTest (FakeBookstoreContext);

y.Methodname();

Note : create instance for FakeBookstoreContext